# Open XML: How to save an existing WordprocessingDocument to MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, openxml, memorystream

In my class, I receive a `WordprocessingDocument` object as a return from another method. I know the document was created in-memory (`MemoryStream`).

Now, I need to either get the underlying `MemoryStream` of this `WordprocessingDocument` object, or resave it to a new `MemoryStream`.

I need it as `MemoryStream` so I can transfer it to our repository.

How can I either access the underlying `MemoryStream`, or resave the object to a new `MemoryStream`?

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the `WordprocessingDocument` into a new `MemoryStream` like this:

```
static MemoryStream CloneWordprocessingDocument(WordprocessingDocument document)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Clone(memStream,true);
    memStream.Position = 0;
    return memStream;
}
```

I tested it with a console project below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open("Test.docx", true);

        // Clone the WordprocessingDocument to a MemoryStream
        MemoryStream clonedStream = CloneWordprocessingDocument(wordDocument);

        File.WriteAllBytes("Final.docx", clonedStream.ToArray());
    }

    static MemoryStream CloneWordprocessingDocument(WordprocessingDocument document)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Clone(memStream,true);
        memStream.Position = 0;
        return memStream;
    }
}
```